# Access Local Host Web Application in another Computer

Tags: asp.net

We copied a web application in IIS. When I browse using local host the application is working.We would like to access the same application in another computer within the network without Internet.

The hosted PC will act as a dummy server and the client computer should access the application smoothly as localhost surfing.

Please help.If we put the IP Address the application can access.Is there any another option to access the application within the network without IP browsing.

Answer (score 0):

It is really depends from your local network configuration. Do you have a DNS? Anyways, you can try to reach your server by its computer name (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System).